# Run-time error when copying from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, runtime-error, copy-paste, worksheet-function, vba

I have the code listed below where I want to copy each row that contains the rules within the if statement and pastes them into a second sheet. This is what I have:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
    Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook


    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1

    For i = 5 To Lastrow
        If (IsEmpty(Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)))) Then
            If IsNumeric(Range(Cells(i, 25), Cells(i, 25))) Then
                Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Value = "T"
                Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 24)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 2, 2), Cells(i - 2, 24)).Value
                Range(Cells(i, 26), Cells(i, 26)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 2, 26), Cells(i - 2, 26)).Value
                Range(Cells(i, 28), Cells(i, 28)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 2, 28), Cells(i - 2, 28)).Value
                Range(Cells(i, 30), Cells(i, 36)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 2, 30), Cells(i - 2, 36)).Value
                Range(Cells(i, 38), Cells(i, 39)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 2, 38), Cells(i - 2, 39)).Value
                mainworkBook.Worksheets("a").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
                mainworkBook.Worksheets(“b”).Range(Cells(j,1),Cells(j,1).Select
                mainworkBook.Sheets(“b”).Paste
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

It's giving me an erro on the "mainworkBook.Worksheets(“b”).Range(Cells(j,1),Cells(j,1).Select" line. Any tips?

Comment: Missing closing parentheses on that row perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the parenthesis.

```
   mainworkBook.Worksheets("b").Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select cells on a worksheet that isn't active and you should qualify the Cells calls with the worksheet too. As it happens it's only one cell so you don't need that syntax, and it's easier to copy directly:

```
mainworkBook.Worksheets("a").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=mainworkBook.Worksheets(“b”).Cells(j,1)
```